# array de imagenes JQuery

Tags: jquery

Lo que tengo que realizar es lo siguiente:

1. Como realizar un arreglo de imagenes en JQuery, pero las fuentes ya las tengo en html, es decir, que ya las tengo cargadas desde html nada más es ponerlas en un arreglo, no las quiero en un ul.
2. Después de tener el arreglo que se llame el arreglo "`imagenes`" y hacer lo de la tabla.

Los llame casos para ubicarlos mejor.

- 0 = no aparece.
- 1 = aparece la imagen.

La imagen barco se va a estar moviendo esos pixeles hacia abajo.

```
imagenes____caso1____caso2____caso3____caso4____caso5

barco_______-205px___-200px___-195px___-190px___-185px

obj1__________0________1________1________1________1

obj2__________0________0________1________1________1

esc___________0________0________0________1________1

obj3__________0________0________0________0________1
```

Todo esto lo quiero hacer para que aparezca con un `for` (recorriendo uno por uno segun sea el caso que se quiera) pero no se como hacerle con lo pixeles, se que es entrando en `.css` y en `margin-top` pero quiero hacerle a que en su posicion ya dada desde css sea consecutivo cada 5px.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es crear algun JSON con la estructura de las imágenes, leer ese JSON y asignarle cada objeto del arreglo a un li.. de acuerdo a lo que entendí

Comment: El array ya lo tengo, ahora la cuestion es hacerlo en su respectivo caso para mostrarlo de acuerdo a un for